# Timestamps only comparing to days and not month/year in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp

I am trying to make a condition in my tables to have the submit button appear when the updated_at time + a few more minutes gap (as a sort of restriction), is lesser than the current time, this is stored in variable $time where the updated_at time is added with the $time_gap restriction and converted into date format for comparison, but only compares the days with $currenttime and does not count the month or year, so its taking 31st July > 1st August.
The code for the time variables is here, I first convert the timestamps into strtotime so I can add more time to it ($tmt is extra time and $tmot is updated_at + $tmt) for comparing it with $currenttime later on.

```
                    $timestamps = userData::select('updated_at')->where('username',$username)->get();
                    foreach ($timestamps as $timestamp){
                        $timestamp = $timestamp->updated_at; }
                    $timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
                    $currentstamp = now();
                    $currentstamp = strtotime($currentstamp);
                    $currenttime = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $currentstamp);
                    $timegaps = division::select('time_gap')->where('id',$userdiv)->get();
                    foreach ($timegaps as $timegap){
                        $timegap = $timegap->time_gap; }
                    $tmt = $timegap * 60 * 1; $tmot = $timestamp + $tmt;  $time= date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $tmot);
```

Here is comparison code in PHP:

```html
                      if ($currenttime < $time){
                        }
                      elseif($currenttime >= $time){
                        if ($nextrankdiv==$rankdiv){ ?><tr>
                            
                            <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Promotion</h4>
                                            <button type="btn btn-primary" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body"> Do you want to promote the following user?
                                            <?php echo '<img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user='.$username.'&direction=4&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=2" />' ; ?>
                                            <form method="post" action="{{route('promote.update',['id' => $id ])}}">
                                                {{csrf_field()}}

                                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="oldrank" class="'form-control" value="{{$oldrankid}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="division" class="'form-control" value="{{$nextrankdiv}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="targetname" class="'form-control" value="{{$targetname}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="'form-control" value="{{$id}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                                            </form>
                                            <td align="center"> &nbsp;&nbsp;

                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"> Submit </button>
                                                &nbsp;      &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>  <?php
                        }
                        elseif ($nextrankdiv>$rankdiv){
                        switch ($train) {
                        case 0: ?><tr>
                          
                            <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Promotion</h4>
                                            <button type="btn btn-primary" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body"> Do you want to promote the following user?
                                            <?php echo '<img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user='.$username.'&direction=4&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=2" />' ; ?>
                                            <form method="post" action="{{route('promote.update',['id' => $id ])}}">
                                                {{csrf_field()}}

                                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="oldrank" class="'form-control" value="{{$oldrankid}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="division" class="'form-control" value="{{$nextrankdiv}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="targetname" class="'form-control" value="{{$targetname}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="'form-control" value="{{$id}}" readonly />
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Submit Div" />
                                            </form>
                                            <td align="center"> &nbsp;&nbsp;

                                                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"> Submit </button>
                                                &nbsp;      &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>  <?php
                        break;
                        case 1:               ?><tr>
                            
                            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; <form method="post" action="{{route('promote.update',['id' => $id ])}}">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="oldrank" class="'form-control" value="{{$oldrankid}}" readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="division" class="'form-control" value="{{$nextrankdiv}}" readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="targetname" class="'form-control" value="{{$targetname}}" readonly />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="'form-control" value="{{$id}}" readonly />
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Submit" />
                                </form> &nbsp;  </td><?php
                            break;
                            }                ?>
                            <?php    }
                            }
                            }
                            } ?>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

The comparison is only done for the days hours/min/sec and does not check for the month and year in comparison, I tried using a switch case instead of if elseif, but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by converting the final dates again into strtotime
so for the above code:

```
                    $currenttime = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $currentstamp);
                    $timegaps = division::select('time_gap')->where('id',$userdiv)->get();
                    foreach ($timegaps as $timegap){
                    $timegap = $timegap->time_gap; }
                    $tmt = $timegap * 60 * 1; $tmot = $timestamp + $tmt;  $time= date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $tmot);
                    $currenttime = strtotime($currenttime);
                    $time = strtotime($time)
```